# Node.js regex: Find all CSS properties in a stylesheet not in the comments

Tags: javascript, css, regex, node.js

I am trying to use regex to query all of the attributes inside of a CSS file. My end goal is to be able to take a css file like this:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

and return a list of selectors like this:

`margin, padding, border, font-size, font, vertical-align, display, list-style, quotes, content, border-collapse, border-spacing`

The first step is to create a regular expression than only matches all of the attributes in the css file, and only those that are not selectors (ie. a:hover) or inside of comments.

Right now all I have is `/(?:([\w\d\S\-\_]+)\:)/g`, which works, but still queries selectors and text inside of comments.

Comment: _"and return a list of selectors like this:"_ Is requirement to return _properties_ set at `css` ?

Comment: You could first filter out the comments, and then run your regex

Comment: @guest271314 no I just want to return the attributes themselves. `margin` <- this and not this -> `margin: 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\/\*.*\*\/|(-moz-|-ms-|-o-|-webkit-)+\w+(?=:)/g` to match , remove comment text , vendor prefixes ; `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/[a-z-]+(?=:[^before|after|hover])/ig` to match characters "a" through "z" or "-" case insensitive, followed by ":" , not followed by "before" or "after"

```js
var style = document.querySelector("style");
var props = style.textContent
            // remove comments, vendor prefixes
            .replace(/\/\*.*\*\/|(-moz-|-ms-|-o-|-webkit-)+\w+(?=:)/g,"")
            // negate `:hover`
            .match(/[a-z-]+(?=:[^before|after|hover])/ig);
console.log(props)
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    /* duplicate `content` property here */
    /* content: none; */
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

table:hover {
  color:blue;
  -moz-animation: name 1s;
}
```

Comment: This is good, but I actually need it to do a couple more things. As it is right now this code will still match on `:hover` and other selectors as well as some special selectors like `[href^='https']`. Here is a full example of the stylesheet I'm matching on http://regexr.com/3cih2. I'd also like to have it not match browser-prefix attributes like `-moz-*`

Comment: Maybe I was wrong on that one. I know there was one selector that was returning a false positive, but I can't remember where

Comment: @mascaliente _"I know there was one selector that was returning a false positive, but I can't remember where"_ ? Same link http://regexr.com/3cih2 ? Tried `js` at updated post ?

Answer (score 2):

You may not need regular expressions for this.

You can access the stylesheet with JavaScript, then iterate over the stylesheet's `cssRules` object and split each declaration at `;` then split each property/value pair at the `:` character.

It's worth pointing out that this method will expand the shorthand properties since the `cssText` property consists of the computed properties/values.

```js
function getPropertiesFromStylesheet(stylsheetIndex) {
  var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[stylsheetIndex],
    rules = stylesheet.cssRules,
    properties = [];

  if (stylesheet) {
    Object.keys(rules).forEach(function(key) {
      rules[key].style.cssText.split(';').forEach(function(declaration) {
        if (declaration) {
          properties.push(declaration.split(':')[0].trim());
        }
      });
    });
  }

  return properties;
}

document.body.textContent = getPropertiesFromStylesheet(0);
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but requires browser javascript. This is actually a node.js script

Comment: @mascaliente - so then edit your question to include the relevant tag and avoid wasting anyone else's time. :thumbs-down: